# Como filtrar um array por outro?

Tags: vue.js

Estou tentando usar o filtro com o vue, mas estou tendo dificuldade.

Código:

```
list() {
    var self=this
    const list = this.programas;
    if (_.isEmpty(this.filter)) {
        return list;
    }

    return list.filter(function(item) {
        return item.funcao.indexOf(self.filter) > -1
    })
}
```

Funciona perfeitamente quando passo uma `string` para o filter, porém preciso que o filtro seja um array, como faço?

---

Esse é meu objeto:

```
dsgpProgramas:[
                {  
                    'categoria': 'Entidades',
                    'funcao': 'Cadastro',
                 },
                 {
                    'categoria': 'Entidades',
                    'funcao': 'Operacao',
                }, 
                {
                    'categoria': 'Entidades',
                    'funcao': 'Consulta',
                    }, 
                {
                    'categoria': 'Entidades',
                    'funcao': 'Parametros',
                }, 
              ]
```

esse é meu filtro

```
filtro = ['cadastro','consulta']
```

só funciona quando meu filtro é assim:

```
filtro= ['cadastro']
```

ou seja ele só funciona quando filtro o array por um filtro com um único parametro, mas nesse exemplo preciso que me traga os registros do  array onde a função seja igual ao cadastro ou consulta e não apenas um ou outro.

Comment: Não entendi muito bem o que quer fazer... Pelo que parece, você tem duas informações no seu `data()`, sendo eles o **programas** e o **filter**, certo? e quer ver se o **item** (*programa*) tem a função? Porém ele executa apenas uma vez ejá dá apenas o primeiro resultado, é esse seu problema? (foi o que consegui perceber)

Comment: Digo, quer manter apenas as funções iniciadas em *filter*?
Pode colocar a array/objeto **programas** na pergunta?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O seu problema é que o `indexOf` procura o valor por completo dentro da *array*, então como você está passando uma *array*, a mesma deve estar contida e na mesma ordem dentro do programa, caso contrário é filtrada/removida.

Esse problema pode ser resolvido com um dos dois exemplos abaixo (devem existir outras formas também).

## forEach

Um `foreach` é feito sobre os filtros e é verificado cada um dentro das funções do programa, caso alguma seja encontrada, o laço é quebrado e retornado `true`, caso contrário o laço roda até o fim e retorna `false`.

```
list.filter((item) => {
    self.filter.forEach((filtro) => {
        if(item.indexOf(filtro)){
            return true
        }
    }, this)

    return false
});
```

## Lodash ou _Underscore.js

Pelo seu `_.isEmpty` você deve estar usando um dos dois, então é possível fazer assim (ambos são iguais nesse caso):
O `._intersection` pega todos os valores iguais entre as *arrays* e cria uma nova *array* com esses valores, logo, se tiverem valores iguais a *array* não estará vazia e o filtro retornará true (por conta da negação do `._isEmpty`);

```
list.filter((item) => {
    return !_.isEmpty(_.intersection(item, self.filter));
})
```